# Boot shows flashing cursor and then a DRM FIFO error

Tags: boot, gnome, kernel

So this appears to be an issue with my latest kernel update as if I boot with my older one then all is good.

`Latest Kernel Version` = `5.11.0-25-generic`

`Older Stable Version` = `5.8.0-63-generic`

If I jump into a `tty` and run `startx` it asks me to confirm my keychain password.

Looking at the `journalctl` it looks like this might be why it does not start the gnome session:

```
Aug 13 23:05:48 mithril goa-daemon[2014]: /org/gnome/OnlineAccounts/Accounts/account_1625737448_0: Setting AttentionNeeded to TRUE because EnsureCredentials() failed with: No credentials found in the keyring (goa-error-quark, 4)
Aug 13 23:05:48 mithril goa-daemon[2014]: secret_password_lookup_sync() returned NULL
Aug 13 23:05:48 mithril gnome-keyring-d[2206]: couldn't create system prompt: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.gnome.keyring.SystemPrompter exited with status 1
Aug 13 23:05:48 mithril gnome-keyring-daemon[2206]: couldn't create system prompt: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.gnome.keyring.SystemPrompter exited with status 1
Aug 13 23:05:48 mithril gcr-prompter[2213]: cannot open display: 
Aug 13 23:05:48 mithril dbus-daemon[1924]: [session uid=1000 pid=1924] Activated service 'org.gnome.keyring.SystemPrompter' failed: Process org.gnome.keyring.SystemPrompter exited with status 1
Aug 13 23:05:48 mithril org.gnome.keyring.SystemPrompter[2213]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Aug 13 23:05:48 mithril dbus-daemon[1924]: [session uid=1000 pid=1924] Activating service name='org.gnome.keyring.SystemPrompter' requested by ':1.14' (uid=1000 pid=2206 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --foreground" label="unconfined")
Aug 13 23:05:48 mithril dbus-daemon[1924]: [session uid=1000 pid=1924] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.secrets'
Aug 13 23:05:48 mithril gnome-keyring-d[2206]: couldn't access control socket: /run/user/1000/keyring/control: No such file or directory
Aug 13 23:05:48 mithril gnome-keyring-daemon[2206]: couldn't access control socket: /run/user/1000/keyring/control: No such file or directory
Aug 13 23:05:48 mithril dbus-daemon[1924]: [session uid=1000 pid=1924] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.secrets' requested by ':1.10' (uid=1000 pid=2014 comm="/usr/libexec/goa-daemon " label="unconfined")
```

This is on ThinkPad X1.

Any thoughts on what I should look at here?

As requested in the comment below from @heynnema `ls -al boot`:

```
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 Aug 10 08:26 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root     4096 Jul  8 10:37 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   253599 Jul 13 17:25 config-5.11.0-25-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   248322 Jul 15 14:51 config-5.8.0-63-generic
drwx------  7 root root     4096 Jan  1  1970 efi
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 Aug 10 08:26 grub
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       28 Aug  9 08:29 initrd.img -> initrd.img-5.11.0-25-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 53029061 Aug  9 08:29 initrd.img-5.11.0-25-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 54078701 Jul 22 12:27 initrd.img-5.8.0-63-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       27 Aug  9 08:29 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-5.8.0-63-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   182704 Aug 18  2020 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184380 Aug 18  2020 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184884 Aug 18  2020 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1 root root  5833109 Jul 13 17:25 System.map-5.11.0-25-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  5534491 Jul 15 14:51 System.map-5.8.0-63-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       25 Aug  9 08:29 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-5.11.0-25-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 10125664 Jul 13 17:43 vmlinuz-5.11.0-25-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  9800288 Jul 15 15:06 vmlinuz-5.8.0-63-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       24 Aug  9 08:29 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-5.8.0-63-generic
```

`dmidecode -s bios-version`

```
N32ET47W (1.23 )
```

Machine is a `ThinkPad X1 Carbon Gen9`
Model is `20XW-0055UK`

I think the Graphics is inegrated with the `Integrated Intel® Iris® Xe Graphics` so not NVIDIA.

```
Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
```

I have not edited the grub menu at boot time before so if you can provide / point me at some instructions that would be great.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /boot`.

Comment: Thanks for the data. However, make sure to send a comment to the requester that you've updated the info, otherwise we'll miss your updates. Start comments to me with @heynnema. Edit your question and show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the EXACT make/model # of your computer. Also, do you know how to edit the GRUB menu at boot time to add nomodeset, or do you need instructions? What video card do you have... internal Intel... or Nvidia? What version Ubuntu?

Comment: @heynnema Thanks for the responses thus far and pointers. I have added the additional information that you requested.

Comment: Please see my answer. If it helps to resolve the problem, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**DRM FIFO error**

This looks to be a video driver buffer error. You have an Intel® Iris® Xe Graphics system. There are no driver updates available for the Intel (unless you update to Ubuntu 21.04).

We'll try and boot with `nomodeset` to temporarily disable the video driver and see if there's any change in behavior.

- Boot to the GRUB menu

  - Use ESC to view the GRUB menu if it doesn't show by default
- Highlight the default boot line
- Hit the <kbd>e</kbd> key to enter edit mode
- Find "quiet splash" and change it to "quiet splash nomodeset"
- Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd>to continue booting
- Observe if you're able to fully boot

**RAMdisk**

Your boot may be stopping at the black screen (of death) when trying to load the RAMdisk. Note the file size difference between the following two RAMdisk files. The one for 5.11.0-25-generic is smaller, and although not impossible, it suggests that maybe it's corrupted. We'll rebuild it.

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 53029061 Aug  9 08:29 initrd.img-5.11.0-25-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 54078701 Jul 22 12:27 initrd.img-5.8.0-63-generic
```

- Boot to kernel 5.8.0-63-generic
- `sudo update-initramfs -c -k 5.11.0-25-generic`
- Boot to kernel 5.11.0-25-generic
- Observe if you're able to fully boot

**BIOS**

Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon Gen9, Model is 20XW-0055UK

You have BIOS version N32ET47W (1.23). There's a newer BIOS available, version N32ET68W (1.44) dated 2021/07/28, and can be downloaded [here](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds548819-bios-update-utility-bootable-cd-for-windows-10-64-bit-thinkpad-x1-carbon-9th-gen-x1-yoga-6th-gen).

**Note**: Read the n32ul09w.txt README notes for Linux/Ubuntu.

**Note**: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your model #.

**Note**: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

**Ubuntu**

You have Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. You may need to update to Ubuntu 21.04.

Comment: thanks for the above - very clear and helpful. nomodeset did not allow the system to boot. Rebuilding the ram disk also did not have effect (and it was still a bit smaller). I have patched the BIOS to the latest level and still no improvement. I have since purged the newer kernel from the system. I was then going to wait for the next kernel update (to see if that had any effect) and also in parallel I will look to update to 21.04. I will update this thread accordingly when I have some more info.

Comment: @PhilSmith Please keep me posted. Just booting to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB 21.04 should tell you something, without having to actually upgrade/install 21.04.

Comment: @PhilSmith Status please...

Comment: @PhilSmith Status please...